# How add an usb to Ethernet interface to a docker container

Tags: networking, usb, ethernet, docker, container

I have an ubuntu 22.04 OS. Currently I have PCI ethernet connection up and running and I also have a running docker container with eth0 connected to default docker bridge. The commutation flow is up and running. I can ping google (8.8.8.8) both from host terminal and from inside docker container.

Now I would to add usb to Ethernet on the host machine and would like to show up only inside running container. Host system should be completely unaware of this new USB to Ethernet network interface (May be using some cgroups and namespace... I don't know how)

Can any one suggest any Linux command that can be executed both on the host machine and inside the container once the USB to Ethernet is plugged on the host machine inorder to achieve the above requirements.

Thank you